# Integrate LDAP with Activiti Explorer

Tags: ldap, openldap, activiti, ldapconnection

I want to configure my LDAP with activiti explorer so I have followed the instructions from the user guide and i created activiti-custom-context.xml file and I did what he said but it didn't work for me and give me this error
in the tomcat log

```
    03:43:35,413 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext  - Error while closing command context
org.activiti.engine.ActivitiIllegalArgumentException: This query is not supported by the LDAPGroupManager
    at org.activiti.ldap.LDAPGroupManager.findGroupByQueryCriteria(LDAPGroupManager.java:94)
    at org.activiti.ldap.LDAPGroupManager.findGroupCountByQueryCriteria(LDAPGroupManager.java:100)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.GroupQueryImpl.executeCount(GroupQueryImpl.java:118)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.AbstractQuery.execute(AbstractQuery.java:170)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvoker.execute(CommandInvoker.java:24)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContextInterceptor.execute(CommandContextInterceptor.java:57)
    at org.activiti.spring.SpringTransactionInterceptor$1.doInTransaction(SpringTransactionInterceptor.java:47)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133)
    at org.activiti.spring.SpringTransactionInterceptor.execute(SpringTransactionInterceptor.java:45)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.LogInterceptor.execute(LogInterceptor.java:31)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.cfg.CommandExecutorImpl.execute(CommandExecutorImpl.java:40)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.cfg.CommandExecutorImpl.execute(CommandExecutorImpl.java:35)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.AbstractQuery.count(AbstractQuery.java:157)
    at org.activiti.explorer.conf.DemoDataConfiguration.createGroup(DemoDataConfiguration.java:118)
    at org.activiti.explorer.conf.DemoDataConfiguration.initDemoGroups(DemoDataConfiguration.java:108)
    at org.activiti.explorer.conf.DemoDataConfiguration.init(DemoDataConfiguration.java:84)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:349)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:133)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:408)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1558)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.activiti.explorer.servlet.WebConfigurer.contextInitialized(WebConfigurer.java:40)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5016)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5524)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1081)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1877)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
03:43:35,417 [localhost-startStop-1] WARN  org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext  - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'demoDataConfiguration': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.activiti.engine.ActivitiIllegalArgumentException: This query is not supported by the LDAPGroupManager
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:408)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1558)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.activiti.explorer.servlet.WebConfigurer.contextInitialized(WebConfigurer.java:40)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5016)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5524)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1081)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1877)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.activiti.engine.ActivitiIllegalArgumentException: This query is not supported by the LDAPGroupManager
    at org.activiti.ldap.LDAPGroupManager.findGroupByQueryCriteria(LDAPGroupManager.java:94)
    at org.activiti.ldap.LDAPGroupManager.findGroupCountByQueryCriteria(LDAPGroupManager.java:100)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.GroupQueryImpl.executeCount(GroupQueryImpl.java:118)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.AbstractQuery.execute(AbstractQuery.java:170)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvoker.execute(CommandInvoker.java:24)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContextInterceptor.execute(CommandContextInterceptor.java:57)
    at org.activiti.spring.SpringTransactionInterceptor$1.doInTransaction(SpringTransactionInterceptor.java:47)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133)
    at org.activiti.spring.SpringTransactionInterceptor.execute(SpringTransactionInterceptor.java:45)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.LogInterceptor.execute(LogInterceptor.java:31)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.cfg.CommandExecutorImpl.execute(CommandExecutorImpl.java:40)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.cfg.CommandExecutorImpl.execute(CommandExecutorImpl.java:35)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.AbstractQuery.count(AbstractQuery.java:157)
    at org.activiti.explorer.conf.DemoDataConfiguration.createGroup(DemoDataConfiguration.java:118)
    at org.activiti.explorer.conf.DemoDataConfiguration.initDemoGroups(DemoDataConfiguration.java:108)
    at org.activiti.explorer.conf.DemoDataConfiguration.init(DemoDataConfiguration.java:84)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:349)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:133)
    ... 25 more
```

this is my activiti-custom-context.xml  file

```
       <bean id="processEngineConfiguration" class="org.activiti.spring.SpringProcessEngineConfiguration">
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
<property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
<property name="databaseSchemaUpdate" value="true" />
<property name="jobExecutorActivate" value="true" />
<property name="enableDatabaseEventLogging" value="true" />
<property name="customFormTypes">
<list>
<bean class="org.activiti.explorer.form.UserFormType" />
<bean class="org.activiti.explorer.form.ProcessDefinitionFormType" />
<bean class="org.activiti.explorer.form.MonthFormType" />
</list>
</property>
<property name="configurators">
<list>
<bean class="org.activiti.ldap.LDAPConfigurator">
<!-- Server connection params -->
<property name="server" value="ldap://localhost" />
<property name="port" value="8389" />
<property name="securityAuthentication" value="simple" />
<property name="user" value="uid=admin,ou=system" />
<property name="password" value="secret" />
<!-- Query params -->
<!--<prMY Coperty name="baseDn" value="dc=test,dc=com" />-->
<property name="baseDn" value="o=mojo" />
<!--HANGE END -->
<property name="queryUserByUserId"
value="(&amp;(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)(displayname={0}))" />
<property name="queryUserByFullNameLike"
value="(&amp;(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)(|({0}=*{1}*)({2}=*{3}*)))" />
<property name="queryGroupsForUser"
value="(&amp;(objectClass=groupOfUniqueNames)(uniqueMember={0}))" />

<property name="userIdAttribute" value="uid" />
<property name="userFirstNameAttribute" value="cn" />
<property name="userLastNameAttribute" value="sn" />

<property name="groupIdAttribute" value="cn" />
<property name="groupNameAttribute" value="cn" />
</bean>
</list>
</property>

</bean>
```

Comment: did you get the solution?